# RuntimeError: Model class users.models.Profile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

This is my **settings.py** file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'products',
'pages',
'register',
'crispy_forms'
]
```

And my **forms.py** file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

And finally my **models.py** file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self):
    super().save()

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

I'm trying to create a User Profile Update page and i'm facing an error with respect to importing the user profile model. Not sure why i'm facing this issue and looked digged a lot into making changes in the 'Installed Apps' and 'models'. How do I resolve this error. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In which Django app, are the models defined?

Comment: @GouravChawla the models are defined in the 'users' app in django.

Comment: `from .models import Profile` - where is the Profile model defined?